# Valor ASCII para char ou valor Int para ASCII C

Tags: c, int, conversão, char, ascii

Galera, preciso buscar um valor encontrado por um `rand` em um arquivo, estou tendo muito problemas pois o `rand` me retorna um inteiro e para buscar caractere em um arquivo o `fgetc` me retorna um inteiro correspondente ao ASCII do caractere. Eu não estou conseguindo nem converter o inteiro para seu valor ASCII e nem converter o numero ASCII encontrado para char.

Alguém consegue me dar uma luz? Obrigado

Comment: Mostre o que já fez e indique onde está o problema.

Comment: ja tentou usar fscanf ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode criar uma variável do tipo char, e igualar ela ao valor inteiro, depois é só comparar o char com o valor do arquivo.

```js
char c;

c = 125;
```

Isso acontece porque o tipo char é uma variável de 1 byte, cujo o valor vai de 0~255.